# How to get Polymer working with Meteor?

Tags: meteor, polymer

I'm trying to get Polymer 0.9 working with Meteor however Meteor is spitting out:

```
While building the application:
   bower_components/polymer/polymer-micro.html:9: bad formatting in HTML template
   bower_components/polymer/polymer-mini.html:9: bad formatting in HTML template
   bower_components/polymer/polymer.html:17: bad formatting in HTML template

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

Is there any way to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the components in public/ at the root of your project.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problems. I can't tell if you're using vulcanize, but I assume so.
What fixed me was:
Install Bower: `npm install -g bower` (bower.org)
Create a file in the root of the project called .bowerrc

Then, you want to tell bower where to install polymer components.
In that .bowerrc put:

```
{
    "directory": "public/bower_components"
}
```

Now, use bower to install polymer

`bower install --save Polymer/polymer#^1.2.0`

If you're using other parts of polymer like paper and iron, you'll repeat the bower install step for those as well.

Then attempt starting up meteor again.